# gradle + idea: can not resolve systemProperty in build.gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

To run tests with jni helper library I add such code into `build.gradle`:

```
def jniLibDir = "xxx"
tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", jniLibDir
}
```

and `./gradlew build` works without problems,
but `idea` reports error:

> Can not resolve symbol systemProperty

and if run test under `idea` it throw java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception.

How help to `idea` to understand where take my `dll` with jni code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related issue:

- [IDEA-160675](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160675) Making Gradle system properties available to IDEA's test runner

You will need to add `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir/with/native/libs` into IntelliJ IDEA Run/Debug configuration **VM Options** field. This can be changed for the configuration under **Defaults** node so that it's added automatically to all the new tests you run from the right click menu.